# Como utilizar a tradução do WYSIHTML5?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3

A documentação diz o seguinte:

> You can use Bootstrap-wysihtml5 in other languages. There are some
>   translations available in the src/locales directory. You can include
>   your desired one after the plugin and pass its key to the editor.
>   Example:
>
> ```
> $('#some-textarea').wysihtml5({locale: "pt-BR"});
> ```

Mas mesmo assim não estou conseguindo invocá-la. O que pode estar acontecendo?

**Bibliotecas**:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.min.css">
<script src="public/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/locales/bootstrap-wysihtml5.pt-BR.js"></script>
<script src="public/plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js"></script>
```

**Script**:

```
$(function () {
  //bootstrap WYSIHTML5 - text editor
  $('.textarea').wysihtml5({
    locale: "pt-BR",
    toolbar:
    {
      "font-styles": true, // Font styling, e.g. h1, h2, etc.
      "emphasis": true, // Italics, bold, etc.
      "lists": true, // (Un)ordered lists, e.g. Bullets, Numbers.
      "html": false, // Button which allows you to edit the generated HTML.
      "link": false, // Button to insert a link.
      "image": false, // Button to insert an image.
      "color": false, // Button to change color of font
      "blockquote": true, // Blockquote,
      parser: function(html) {
          return html.text();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: será pela falta ); na penultima }  ?

Comment: Pelo que entendi vc deveria carregar `/bootstrap-wysihtml5.pt-BR.js` por último, ou seja, após `bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.min.js`.

Comment: @André, há mais código abaixo e esqueci de fechar no trecho acima.

Comment: @Sam, nossa. Desculpa pela ignorância, mas onde diz (e o porquê) que deve ser carregado após? Mas funcionou.

Comment: Tá dizendo aqui: `You can include your desired one after the plugin`... **after the plugin**

Comment: @Sam, nossa havia desconsiderado totalmente essa seção **Stylesheets** (mas que formatação _trash_).